# Does Debian kernel supports hwe?

Tags: linux, debian, hardware

So recently faced some issues, that HW transcoding is not working on Debian 9.11. Having E3-1275v6, that has iGPU.

I know, that for Ubuntu, there is a 'special' kernel that needs to be installed(linux-generic-hwe), but what about Debian? For now, I'm using a custom kernel(xanmod).

Cheers!

Comment: The closest thing I'm aware of is backports. https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/linux-image-amd64 http://jensd.be/818/linux/install-a-newer-kernel-in-debian-9-stretch-stable

Comment: @Mikel Hey! Thank you! And how to install it in correct way?

Comment: Welcome! I haven't tried it, but the second link in my comment above may help

Comment: @Mikel Sad to say, that I've installed all + drivers but it haven't worked :(